# r - consolidate rows in dataframe by removing empty spaces

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

This question is similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41523123/combine-multiple-columns-excluding-null-values), but not the same. I have an extremely large and messy data frame from an OCR'd old document. It's full of empty values that I need to collapse to form consolidated rows. Take the following example:

```
DF <- data.frame(
  Col1 = c("Egg", "", ""),
  Col2 = c("", "Flour", ""),
  Col3 = c("", "", "Bread"),
  Col4 = c("4", "", ""),
  Col5 = c("", "6", "8")
)

> DF
  Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4 Col5
1  Egg                4     
2      Flour               6
3            Bread         8
```

How do I remove the empty values of the dataframe to form consolidated rows? The desired output looks like this:

```
> DF
  Col1    Col2
1  Egg    4     
2  Flour  6
3  Bread  8
```

The actual dataframe is very large with rows containing varied number of empty values.

Comment: try: `t(apply(DF, 1, function(x) x[x != ""]))`

Comment: This worked for the example above but not for my actual dataframe, not sure why. It produces a one row dataframe with too many columns...

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `coalesce()` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
DF[DF==""] <- NA # replace empty strings by NA
data.frame(Col1 = coalesce(!!! DF), Col2 = coalesce(!!! rev(DF)))
#   Col1 Col2
#1   Egg    4
#2 Flour    6
#3 Bread    8
```

Answer (score 0):

yet, another approach to implement  the same

```
library(dplyr)

df<-do.call("paste", DF)%>%as.data.frame()

df<- df%>%
  transmute(x1= df[[1]]%>%str_extract("[A-z]+"),
            x2 = df[[1]]%>%str_extract("\\d+"))
df

#     x1 x2
#1   Egg  4
#2 Flour  6
#3 Bread  8
```

@mtoto still worth more credits